# WP_Query for post relationship and custom post type

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, function

How to write query for getting child post id of the parent post from a different table in Wordpress?

I have many custom post types in Wordpress,
Each post type have many child post type Like this:

California School > Video 1 , Video 4 , Video 7

{School and Video are custom post types}

I have a table like this:

[Table name is kg_toolset_associations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kxo9U.png)

(This table created by Toolset plugin.)

I'd like to get the ID of all videos that associates to parent school;

I wrote this query :

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT `child_id`  FROM `kg_toolset_associations` WHERE `relationship_id` = `4` AND `parent_id` = `8568`, OBJECT );
?>
```

- I have tried to follow the advice from [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11321508/1690217) but using back ticks still does not work.

Comment: Table and column names in mysql should either be enclosed in backticks or not at all.  Single quotes produces something very different (or just an error).